# Difference between 2 statements

Tags: java, double

There is a difference in the result between these 2 statements. Can anyone enlighten me as to why?

```
double x2 = (-b-Math.sqrt(b*b-4.0*a*c))/(2*a);

double x2 = (-b-Math.sqrt(b*b-4.0*a*c))/2*a;
```

Comment: what is difference share here

Answer (score 4):

Both `*` and `/` have the same [operator presedence](http://web.deu.edu.tr/doc/oreily/java/langref/ch04_14.htm).

That means that if you don't surround them with braces, they will just be executed left-to-right.

In the case of the first statement, you are dividing by the value of `2 * a`, however, in the second statement you are dividing by 2, then multiplying by `a`.

If I'm correct in assuming this is related to the quadratic formula, then the first statement is correct.

Answer (score 3):

```
44 / 2 * 2 = 44

44 / (2 * 2) = 11

(44 / 2) * 2 = 44
```

Answer (score 2):

To simplify, let's replace the identical portion, `(-b-Math.sqrt(b*b-4.0*a*c))`, in both statements with `y`.

The first statement is:

```
double x2 = y/(2*a);
```

This means that a is multiplied by 2, and y is divided by the result of that.

The second statement is:

```
double x2 = y/2*a;
```

This means that y is divided by 2, then a is multiplied by that result.  It is equivalent to:

```
double x2 = (y*a)/2;
```

Answer (score 2):

Java does math from left to right (see comment). In your first declaration the sqrt value is divided by (2*a), as in it's divided by twice the value of a. In the second declaration your sqrt value is divided by 2 and then multiplied by a. This causes the difference between your two values. Hope this helps.

Comment: It's not always just "left to right".  Without parentheses, a division or multiplication would be executed prior to an addition or subtraction, regardless of the order they appear in the statement.

Comment: The above comment is correct. Most languages which support mathematical operations also follow normal mathematical prescedence in terms of parentheses, then multiplication and division, and then addition and subtraction.

Answer (score 0):

simplify the equation as:

```
double x2 = B / (2 * a)

double x2 = B / 2 * a
```

for the first equation,
it will first compute the products of `2` and `a`, then `B/product`

for the second equation,
it will first compute `B/2`, the use the result to multiply `a`